# eval function in React Native

Tags: react-native

I need a way to execute code with the eval javascript function ( or something like that ) but I get an error with code below ( why? ) :

```
...
const mathsignarray = ["+", "-", "x", "÷"];

class Letsdoit extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      a: 15,
      b: 17,
      mathsign: mathsignarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)],
    }

    this.result = eval(this.state.a this.state.mathsign this.state.b);

  }
...
```

Comment: try : `eval(this.state.a + this.state.mathsign + this.state.b);`

Comment: @Cherniv error: invalid character \u0247

Comment: @Cherniv is right and `x` should be `*` and `÷` should be `/`